# How to make Error List window automatically active during compilation in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide, automation

How to make Error List window automatically active during compilation in visual studio instead of default Output window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Options / Projects and Solutions / General / Always show error List...

You can also uncheck the "Show Output window when build starts" if needed.